# How to send ajax callback param with Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to send an Ajax callback with RequestContext but I can't get it work.

I tried the [Primefaces login demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf), but  "args.loggedIn" in the javascript function is always undefined, whereas "args" is an Object.

Here is my code:

dialogLogin.xhtml:

```html
<h:body>
<h:outputLink
        id="loginLink" 
        value="javascript:void(0)" 
        onclick="dlg.show()"
        title="login">
        Click
</h:outputLink>

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg">  
    <h:form>  

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />  
            <p:inputText value="#{logBean.username}"   
                    id="username" required="true" label="username" />  

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />  
            <h:inputSecret value="#{logBean.password}"   
                    id="password" required="true" label="password" />  

            <f:facet name="footer">  
                <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" update=""   
                    actionListener="#{logBean.login}"   
                    oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </h:panelGrid>  

    </h:form>  
</p:dialog>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {  
        if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {  
            jQuery('#dialog').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);  
        } else {  
            dlg.hide();  
            jQuery('#loginLink').fadeOut();  
        }  
    }  
</script>
</h:body>
```

LogBean.java:

```java
@ManagedBean
public class LogBean {  

    private String username;      
    private String password;  

    // getters & setters

    public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
        boolean loggedIn = false;  

        if(username != null  && username.equals("admin") && password != null  && password.equals("admin")) {  
            loggedIn = true;  
        } else {  
            loggedIn = false;  
        }  
        System.out.println("loggedIn : " + loggedIn);
        context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);  
    }
}
```

The javascript function "handleLoginRequest" is called, but "args.loggedIn" is always undefined. I can't understand why...

Response sent (I get it from Firebug) is:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<partial-response>
    <changes>
        <update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
            <![CDATA[3585116548358262356:-8608378680794066522]]>
        </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the scope of the managed bean?

Comment: I tried SessionScoped, ViewScoped, RequestScoped... The result is the same in all cases.

Comment: I tried to run your example and it worked fine. How you are checking is `args` undefined or not? Have you tried to do `console.log(args)` before `if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn)`?

Comment: I tried to write "args" and "args.loggedIn" in the console:

args = [object Object]
args.loggedIn = undefined

Comment: this means that `args` isn't `undefined` as you stated in your post. It is an Object. Problem solved?

Comment: Indeed it is, but it seems to be empty: my parameter is undefined.
I was wrong in my post, I meant my parameter is undefined.

Comment: Please correct your post. While the validation fails it will be undefined. If the validation passes it is either true or false, depending on your input values. What's your actual problem?

Comment: My problem is that "args.loggedIn" is undefined. You said if "validationFailed" is true, my parameter will always be undefined, right? But I don't really understand how it works? If I print "args.validationFailed" it's also undefined, even if in my bean "loggedIn" is true.

Comment: have you tried to reproduce this issue within a new project, containing only the login page and similar code like the PrimeFaces showcase has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the validation fails you get the following response from the application:

```
<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension>
```

which contains a JSON response containing *only* `validationFailed : true`. There is no `loggedIn` field in the response this is the reason why it is `undefined` is you call `args.loggedIn`.

If the validation passes but the login fails you will get the following response:

```
<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"loggedIn":false}</extension>
```

this response has the `loggedIn` value so calling `args.loggedIn` results in `false`. Because there is no `validationFailed` in the JSON response calling `args.validationFailed` results in undefined.

Comment: Ok, so we should always have "validationFailed" or "loggedIn" in the response. But in my case, both are undefined! (I "console.log" just before the "if" in the JS function).

Comment: Is the [Dialog - Login Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf) works for you? Are you getting  the expected JSON responses (like I described in my answer)? Which browser are you using?

Comment: This demo still doesn't work for me. I updated my first post with the response I get from Firebug (I can see it in the Firebug javascript console, maybe I do it wrong?)
I tried with Firefox and Chromium, I have the same result with both.

Comment: Your code looks fine, with copy&paste it works for me. Is the original demo on the PrimeFaces showcase works for you?

Comment: On the Primefaces showcase, it's working, but still not if I just copy/paste all the code on my environment...
And if I check with FireBug on the showcase, I can see the "extension" tag with the Json, as you said.

Comment: Speaking from experience, when something totally [unexpected happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281507/prevent-double-submit-on-jsf-dialog-ajax-crud) it's mostly due to a JavaScript error somewhere, on the same page. I would recommend you to create a demo project including only the login page and the required backing bean, then see what happens.