# Prevent Double Submit on JSF Dialog AJAX CRUD

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

Just would like to know why do I encounter this behavior in my application.

I used primefaces for the UI and almost all of my pages follows this pattern.  I heavily used AJAX in all of my CRUD
operations and using dialogs to show it to the user.

```
<ui:composition template="myTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <ui:include
            src="/pages/CreateDialog.xhtml" />
        <ui:include
            src="/pages/UpdateDialog.xhtml" />
        <ui:include
            src="/pages/DeleteDialog.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My only concern is that, after doing CRUD stuff in my dialogs and user accidentally clicks F5 or refresh on the browser,
FF/Chrome and other browser always mentioned

```
To display this page, Firefox must send repeat action...
```

Obviously this will cause double submit.  Previously I used Post-Redirect-Get in this scenario in older apps but since this
is AJAX JSF update then I cannot do this.

What's the workaround for this and is this normal?  I thought AJAX actions should not trigger again during browser refresh.

Help?

**UPDATE**

I am opening my dialog with this code

```
<p:commandButton value="Add" 
        onclick="createWidget.show();"
        update=":CreateForm"
        action="#{MyBean.add}" 
        />
```

My create dialog uses this

```
<p:dialog  header="Create">
    <h:form id="CreateForm" prependId="false">
        <p:commandButton value="Add" icon="ui-icon-plus"
            actionListener="#{MyBean.add}"
            update=":messageGrowl" 
            oncomplete="closeDialogIfSucess(xhr, status, args, createWidget 'createDialogId')"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I actually am following the pages from this site...[Full WebApplication JSF EJB JPA JAAS](http://uaihebert.com/?p=834)

Comment: That's indeed impossible if you're using ajax only. Is the page been opened beforehand by a synchronous POST request or so? Perhaps you're navigating by commandlinks instead of normal (output)links?

Comment: But apparently that is the case for me.  I have updated my post for added information

Comment: Check firebug also and found out that my commandbutton is firing a synchronous request instead of ajax style.  I tried setting the property ajax="true" but this does not fixed the problem.  Any hints please why the button is behaving this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already experienced a few times that having JavaScript errors in callback methods ends up in such behavior. I was able to reproduce your problem which is disappeared after correcting the callback signature:

```
oncomplete="closeDialogIfSucess(xhr, status, args, createWidget, 'createDialogId')"
```

accordingly to you JavaScript function signature:

```
function closeDialogIfSucess(xhr, status, args, createWidget, dialogid)
```

(Sure if your JavaScript call has only 3 parameters then correct the `oncomplete` call)

Unrelated: I guess that you are using this function to close a specific dialog. Another way doing it would be assigning `widgetVar` attribute to your dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="testDialog"  header="Create" widgetVar="createWidget">
    <h:form id="CreateForm" prependId="false">
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The `widgetVar` object will represent your dialog in the callback function so you can close it by call the `hide()` function of dialog:

```
function closeDialogIfSucess(xhr, status, args, createWidget) {
    if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {  
        jQuery('#testDialog').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);  
    } else {  
        createWidget.hide();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: hahaha.... exactly! Javascript Error's really is the cause as I missed one comma in my callback.... Thank you so much!